# How to hide HUD elements?

Tags: pc, middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I would like to remove HUD elements on PC version of Shadow of Mordor in order to have more immersion and take bettere screenshot.

Are there some commands that I can write in console to obtain that effect (and if you can tell me also how to enter open up the console would be nice)?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the visual things you can turn off:

> - combat prompts (the triangle above the enemies head)
> - Enemy outlines
> - Combat hints
> - Enemy awareness icons
> - mission objectives

So basically the answer right now is **NO** you can't turn off the HUD. Like mini-map and such.

Maybe in the future they will release a patch that may allow us to remove hud from the screen.